# I have returned a property grid and applied validation to it. When it is an error value then it retains and shows the last correct value entered

Tags: validation, extjs

I have a property grid and applied validation to it. When I input an error value then it retains and shows the last correct value entered and not the error value inputed.

Answer (score 0):

Property grid has the feature of retaining the last correct value if the entered value is incorrect format. So it prevents from entering the wrong data and it doesnot show error data.